# multiple directives with export as

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

```
<form novalidate class="mt-2" #paramForm="ngForm" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)">
```

I got the following hint from webstorm:

[image]

Is there a way to access ngForm instance exported by formGroupDirective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only use either one of those:

```
#paramForm="ngForm"         // This pertains to Template Driven Form

or

[formGroup]="form"         // This pertains to Reactive Form
```

So if you are using a **Template driven form** where you will specify the controls on [(ngModel)] on your **template**, use `#paramForm="ngForm"`

```
<form novalidate 
      class="mt-2" 
      #paramForm="ngForm" 
      (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)">
```

But if not and you are using a **Reactive form** where you specify your FormControls on your **component** by either using a FormBuilder/FormGroup/FormControl, use `[formGroup]="form"`

```
<form novalidate 
      class="mt-2" 
      [formGroup]="form"
      (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)">
```

---

> Have created a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-trigger-save-outside-component) as per your concern below. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, you are completly right, but I need the template driven way...because I want submit the form from outside, the form itself is build by formBuilder. For example: (click)="paramForm.ngSubmit.emit()" so i need both?

Comment: If the form itself is built by a FormBuilder. You must only use the [formGroup]="form". Would like to clarify, so you want to trigger the submit button from ComponentA  to ComponentB where your form resides ?

Comment: I have added an example if its what you're looking for.

Comment: @KShewebgger Thanks, not really, I will trigger ist from form component itself. But from a button outside the <form> tag.

Comment: Hi @robert I have created a Stackblitz pasted above of my answer. Hope that helps. This will trigger the Save button on your FormComponent from the outside Component

Comment: @KSewengger Help's a lot! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I am using both the ngForm directive and the formGroup directive without getting that error in Angular 7 so long as I only import ReactiveFormsModule and not both that one and the FormsModule.  That could be your problem.

Example:

```
<form [formGroup]="inviteForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #formDir="ngForm">
  <span *ngIf="formDir.submitted && !inviteForm.get('firstName').valid; else otherErrorMessage">First name invalid</span>
</form>
```

Comment: This is true but if anywhere else you want to use ngModel or anything from FormsModule you will not be able. So this is definitely not a solution.